# CustomUserStore with custom User entity error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

This is identity and service add
i am referecing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<CPSContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

   services.AddTransient<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, CustomUserStore> ();  --have to replace IdentityUser with User class 

    services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, CustomRoleStore>();
```

CustomRoleStore Class

```
 public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<IdentityUser>  ---i have to replace IdentityUser with User class which inherited from IdentityUser 
    {
        public CustomUserStore(CPSContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            AutoSaveChanges = false;
        }
    }


public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<IdentityRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(CPSContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            AutoSaveChanges = false;
        }
    }
```

But in am not using IdentityUser class

```
namespace Domain.Entities.Security
{
     public class User : IdentityUser<int>
        {
            public string? FullName { get; set; }
            public string? UIN { get; set; }
    
      }
}
```

But when i replaced with IdentityUser with Custom User Class

```
 public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<User>
    {
        .....
    }
```

I am getting below error

[image: error]

```
Is it is possible to use Custom User instead of default IdentityUser?
```

[![ere][2]][2]

Comment: Why do you have `Domain.Entities.Security`? I don't know this package, but it looks like it also has `User` class that gets pulled instead of the one in Identity package

Comment: Hi that is folder structure..not package...Entity class already in the question.. public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string? FullName { get; set; }
        public string? UIN { get; set; }

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UserStore<TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.userstore-4?view=aspnetcore-7.0) as base class, since you have `int`  as `TKey` type.

The generic definition [`UserStore<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.userstore-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) assume that `TKey` is of type `string`.

Since [`UserStore<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.userstore-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (see the doc from the link) is defined as:

```
public class UserStore<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,string>
```

and you must change the `TKey` to `int`, I imagine the correct definition could be (or replace `IdentityRole` and `DbContext` with your own if you defined your own) :

```
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<User,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,int>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer can u please sample code in the answer..i  made 2 class 1 for userstore and another rolestore only for AutoSaveChanges = false;

Comment: I added sample code, but refer to the documentation to have more info about it.

Comment: Thanks ..i have replaced Role with my custom class... whether i have to create CustomRoleStore  seperately?

Comment: services.AddScoped<IUserStore<User>, CustomUserStore>();
  services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, CustomRoleStore>(); this is my previous code...whether need to changed?

Comment: If you defined your role custom class you must also add the `CustomRoleStore`. Also in this case if you have a `int` key you must inherit from [`RoleStore<TRole,TContext,TKey>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.rolestore-3?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and not from `RoleStore<TRole>` that uses `string` as `TKey`.

Comment: public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<User, Role, CPSContext, int>                
   public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<Role, CPSContext, int> is this correct now error gone..

Comment: I think it could work.

Comment: You already created a custom db context as described in [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0)?  You must define a your own `IdentityDbContext` since you've customized roles and users with a different type of key.